# Получение PostScript имени шрифта.

Tags: c#, pdf, .net, java

Уважаемые знатоки, есть ли возможность получить PostScript имя шрифта в C#, как это, например, сделано в Java? Для справки, в классе `java.awt.Font` есть функция `getPSName()`. Для C# даже после длительных поисков в Интернете и на MSDN решения так и не смог найти.

P.S. Это нужно для работы с PDF документами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать извлечь имя Postscript-шрифта из файла шрифта. Для этого потребуется:

1. получить файл шрифта (путь и имя в системе),
2. прочитать и пропарсить его (например, для TTF-шрифта - в разделе General Font Information).

Comment: Было бы хорошо, но нужно получить это имя стандартными средствами. Сам сижу и поражаюсь, как хвалёный C#.NET не может решить задачу, которую Java судя по документации к getPSName() научилась решать с версии 1.2)